# SQL 2008 DENSE_RANK - Not Working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dense-rank

I'm trying to get a dense_rank function to work hwoever it keeps returning the below :

> ```
> Account |Date       |AuditDateTime          |rnk
> 4127    |2003-12-05 |2003-12-05 09:57:19.000|1
> 4127    |2004-02-02 |2004-02-02 10:34:51.000|1
> 4127    |2004-05-27 |2004-05-27 11:11:53.000|1
> 4127    |2004-10-25 |2004-10-25 10:11:46.000|1
> 4127    |2005-01-27 |2005-01-27 10:26:37.000|1
> ```

The query is :

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Account, Date ORDER BY mx.AuditDateTime DESC) rnk
```

I'm obviouslt missing something obvious but cant see for looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the date's are different you are getting all the row's with `1`. Try removing it from `PARTITION BY`.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY mx.AuditDateTime DESC) rnk
```

Comment: knew it would be soemthing simple. Thanks, that worked spot on!